# Navigate to another URL on browser close

Tags: html, browser

Is there any possibility to divert the request to another URL from browser close event or can we disable browser close button for a particular URL?

Comment: You absolutely cannot prevent a user from closing the browser.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Your body tag's onunload attribute can contain javascript that alert's, but there is very little you can do when the window is closing or the whole browser is shutting down.

Comment: thanks for your reply  i stopped the browser to get closed showing him the alert ... now can we disable the okay button here on the popup ????? just Checking the possibilities .... to stop navigation    var hook = true;
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (hook) {
      return " ======  Please logout of NGCCRM Application ======= "
    }
  }
  function unhook() {
    hook=false;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- this will go without asking: -->
<a href="test.html" onClick="unhook()">internal link, un-hooked</a>

Comment: @JasonBourne you **cannot** prevent the user from closing a browser tab or the whole browser application. It is simply impossible, and an application design that relies on that is therefore inherently broken.

Comment: What you can do, though, is put up an alert with unposted content and give the user a chnce to copy it to their clipboard, but beyond that, the application really is just done.

Comment: Thanks flocks for your quick replies : end up with this code in IE . window.onbeforeunload = function(){             
     if (event.clientY &lt; 0 )  {          
        if (window.ActiveXObject) 
        { 
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
        } 
        else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        { 
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }         
        httpRequest.open("GET", "/jsps/common/logOut.jspx", true); 
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {processRequest(); } ; 
        httpRequest.send(null);        
     }
      }